# Why chrome is not taking whole width when using max-width or width?

Tags: html, css

Im building a site, it is thinked for mobile view but also must be work on web.
I have a parent div width:100% and child div. What I need is keep fixed width child when device is narrow. I use width:100% and max-width: 540px for that. It works on firefox but in chrome the child div is resized.

this is what I need (gif explanation)

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/Us6DEtr" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/Us6DEtr"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

this is what is happening (gif explanation)

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/zoKGKeL" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/zoKGKeL"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and this is the code

```css
 
.land {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.land-background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    z-index: -10;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}

.land-background:before {
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-filter: blur(15px);
    -o-filter: blur(15px);
    -ms-filter: blur(15px);
    filter: blur(15px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
}


.land-background-vedio{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    max-width: 540px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 29px 0 rgb(100 100 111 / 20%);
    z-index: 0;
}

.land-background-vedio video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}

audio, video {
    display: inline-block;
}


.land-main.main-vhcheck {
    min-height: calc(100vh - var(--vh-offset, 0px));
}

.land-main {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.land-main-info {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}



body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Google Sans,SF Pro Display,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}

html {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


article, aside, blockquote, body, button, dd, details, div, dl, dt, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, input, legend, li, menu, nav, ol, p, section, td, textarea, th, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

body, button, html, input, li, p, select, table, td, tr, ul {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <div class="land">
        <div class="land-background is-fixed" style='background-image: url("https://image.mux.com/5zw015Sp01Yl02Ssb00xeotvrZLRXAzqg02UL/thumbnail.jpg?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InQ5UHZucm9ZY0hQNjhYSmlRQnRHTEVVSkVSSXJ0UXhKIn0.eyJ3aWR0aCI6NjQwLCJ0aW1lIjowLCJleHAiOjMxNzE5MjI1MTA5MiwiYXVkIjoidCIsInN1YiI6IjV6dzAxNVNwMDFZbDAyU3NiMDB4ZW90dnJaTFJYQXpxZzAyVUwifQ.B9894ppuWg8SAfzx36ZkeEBK1c3RAWIAmi4VNr1G7cMb_7nSqdiS4ANa2VHMvrS2zsYbZEa8mHle1g4qEWh_T9cuwvW3Dp1ljBuf7CB-9OCH_m-sRlizlBE0wpM4gB-VCtwy3SYLmYOpIUWlwy2WV3fuRMcFRL7_i6f55HfyDLDdcOyNNX1yglX2sVtn83ozPSTQCn9TvvhRCX_P_-CxMN6nE7X39jWriX0UQCZlaEOV_LzkDvtnk2GjTUN1Njn18Rl3Vr-xolPHSVlvMqEGm1EaInsDyF-ULqIYeK8D0LGtQoXOpnTwxOEXgna8qmVtshpPjrnjKpgkF-ODnwxDeA");' >
            <div class="land-background-vedio" >
                <video id="bgVideo" src="https://storage.coverr.co/videos/5zw015Sp01Yl02Ssb00xeotvrZLRXAzqg02UL?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBJZCI6IkUwMUJBMDU2QzEwQkQzQzk1RDRCIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU4NDc0NzU3fQ.EkvxAeyGRO_0el2byPOaVRUnMoiytadrW7cdVRJ7CCM" poster="https://image.mux.com/5zw015Sp01Yl02Ssb00xeotvrZLRXAzqg02UL/thumbnail.jpg?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InQ5UHZucm9ZY0hQNjhYSmlRQnRHTEVVSkVSSXJ0UXhKIn0.eyJ3aWR0aCI6NjQwLCJ0aW1lIjowLCJleHAiOjMxNzE5MjI1MTA5MiwiYXVkIjoidCIsInN1YiI6IjV6dzAxNVNwMDFZbDAyU3NiMDB4ZW90dnJaTFJYQXpxZzAyVUwifQ.B9894ppuWg8SAfzx36ZkeEBK1c3RAWIAmi4VNr1G7cMb_7nSqdiS4ANa2VHMvrS2zsYbZEa8mHle1g4qEWh_T9cuwvW3Dp1ljBuf7CB-9OCH_m-sRlizlBE0wpM4gB-VCtwy3SYLmYOpIUWlwy2WV3fuRMcFRL7_i6f55HfyDLDdcOyNNX1yglX2sVtn83ozPSTQCn9TvvhRCX_P_-CxMN6nE7X39jWriX0UQCZlaEOV_LzkDvtnk2GjTUN1Njn18Rl3Vr-xolPHSVlvMqEGm1EaInsDyF-ULqIYeK8D0LGtQoXOpnTwxOEXgna8qmVtshpPjrnjKpgkF-ODnwxDeA" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="metadata" x5-video-player-type="h5" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" muted="muted"></video>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="land-main main-vhcheck" >
            <div class="land-main-info" >
                <div class="land-list-drag">
                    <span>
                        
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know why, but apparently when I add <!DOCTYPE html> tag it works. Publishing this post makes me realize that when I ran the code snippet it worked. Someone knows why?

Comment: Im on 105.0.5195.102 chrome version

Answer (score 1):

You have set both width and height of **land-background-vedio** to 100% and the dimensions of the 100% are changing independently of each other.  Set either width or height to auto.

```css
.land {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.land-background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    z-index: -10;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}

.land-background:before {
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-filter: blur(15px);
    -o-filter: blur(15px);
    -ms-filter: blur(15px);
    filter: blur(15px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
}


.land-background-vedio{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    max-width: 540px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 29px 0 rgb(100 100 111 / 20%);
    z-index: 0;
}

.land-background-vedio video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}

audio, video {
    display: inline-block;
}


.land-main.main-vhcheck {
    min-height: calc(100vh - var(--vh-offset, 0px));
}

.land-main {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.land-main-info {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}



body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Google Sans,SF Pro Display,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}

html {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


article, aside, blockquote, body, button, dd, details, div, dl, dt, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, input, legend, li, menu, nav, ol, p, section, td, textarea, th, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

body, button, html, input, li, p, select, table, td, tr, ul {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <div class="land">
        <div class="land-background is-fixed" style='background-image: url("https://image.mux.com/5zw015Sp01Yl02Ssb00xeotvrZLRXAzqg02UL/thumbnail.jpg?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InQ5UHZucm9ZY0hQNjhYSmlRQnRHTEVVSkVSSXJ0UXhKIn0.eyJ3aWR0aCI6NjQwLCJ0aW1lIjowLCJleHAiOjMxNzE5MjI1MTA5MiwiYXVkIjoidCIsInN1YiI6IjV6dzAxNVNwMDFZbDAyU3NiMDB4ZW90dnJaTFJYQXpxZzAyVUwifQ.B9894ppuWg8SAfzx36ZkeEBK1c3RAWIAmi4VNr1G7cMb_7nSqdiS4ANa2VHMvrS2zsYbZEa8mHle1g4qEWh_T9cuwvW3Dp1ljBuf7CB-9OCH_m-sRlizlBE0wpM4gB-VCtwy3SYLmYOpIUWlwy2WV3fuRMcFRL7_i6f55HfyDLDdcOyNNX1yglX2sVtn83ozPSTQCn9TvvhRCX_P_-CxMN6nE7X39jWriX0UQCZlaEOV_LzkDvtnk2GjTUN1Njn18Rl3Vr-xolPHSVlvMqEGm1EaInsDyF-ULqIYeK8D0LGtQoXOpnTwxOEXgna8qmVtshpPjrnjKpgkF-ODnwxDeA");' >
            <div class="land-background-vedio" >
                <video id="bgVideo" src="https://storage.coverr.co/videos/5zw015Sp01Yl02Ssb00xeotvrZLRXAzqg02UL?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBJZCI6IkUwMUJBMDU2QzEwQkQzQzk1RDRCIiwiaWF0IjoxNjU4NDc0NzU3fQ.EkvxAeyGRO_0el2byPOaVRUnMoiytadrW7cdVRJ7CCM" poster="https://image.mux.com/5zw015Sp01Yl02Ssb00xeotvrZLRXAzqg02UL/thumbnail.jpg?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InQ5UHZucm9ZY0hQNjhYSmlRQnRHTEVVSkVSSXJ0UXhKIn0.eyJ3aWR0aCI6NjQwLCJ0aW1lIjowLCJleHAiOjMxNzE5MjI1MTA5MiwiYXVkIjoidCIsInN1YiI6IjV6dzAxNVNwMDFZbDAyU3NiMDB4ZW90dnJaTFJYQXpxZzAyVUwifQ.B9894ppuWg8SAfzx36ZkeEBK1c3RAWIAmi4VNr1G7cMb_7nSqdiS4ANa2VHMvrS2zsYbZEa8mHle1g4qEWh_T9cuwvW3Dp1ljBuf7CB-9OCH_m-sRlizlBE0wpM4gB-VCtwy3SYLmYOpIUWlwy2WV3fuRMcFRL7_i6f55HfyDLDdcOyNNX1yglX2sVtn83ozPSTQCn9TvvhRCX_P_-CxMN6nE7X39jWriX0UQCZlaEOV_LzkDvtnk2GjTUN1Njn18Rl3Vr-xolPHSVlvMqEGm1EaInsDyF-ULqIYeK8D0LGtQoXOpnTwxOEXgna8qmVtshpPjrnjKpgkF-ODnwxDeA" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="metadata" x5-video-player-type="h5" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" muted="muted"></video>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="land-main main-vhcheck" >
            <div class="land-main-info" >
                <div class="land-list-drag">
                    <span>
                        
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```